# Nested Resource Route Forms With Has Many - Automatic Linking of Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I see some posts regarding nested resource forms, but none outline how one is supposed to automatically make the nested resource use the parent for the association. When I post my form, it fires the presence validation error "Project Can't be blank"

I have Projects that have many Estimates which have many Line Items.

Now let's say I'm creating a form for estimates at

```
/project/:project_id/estimates/new
```

This form has the has many line items relationship within it. Also note that estimates is a nested resource under projects for my routing.

```
<%= form_for([@project, @estimate], html: {class: "form"}) do |f| %>
...
    <%= f.fields_for :estimate_line_items do |estimate_line_item| %>
...
```

I'd prefer not to post the code for the view, since it's got a LOT of additional elements and structure. Just worth noting that I have no inputs for any IDs anywhere (wondering if this is required or not, see questions).

My questions:

1) How should one create a form in the view code?

2) Does rails automatically link up the associated elements and IDs or do we need to have a hidden input with the ID?

Comment: did you set the `accept_nested_attributes_for :estimate_line_items` on your model and permit the right params? it should handle all the relationships with proper configuration and proper use of the view helpers for most common use cases but you are not showing much to guide you

Comment: Have you already looked at the official Rails [guide about nested forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, since rails 5, `belongs_to` relations are required. That means that the value must be set when saving it. For nested items this means you have two options, either make the `belongs_to` optional, or specifically declare which relations are each other inverse, so rails can deduce the requirement is met *before saving* !

So in your case I would guess something like

```
class Project 
  has_many :estimates, inverse_of: :project 

class Estimate 
  belongs_to :project 
  has_many :estimate_line_items, inverse_of: :estimate  

class EstimateLineItem 
  belongs_to :estimate
```

Also, your case is a bit special, as you have a nested form, on a nested route. The nested form handles all id's auto-magically, but the `@project_id` from the route is not inserted in the form: you have to do that yourself, so do not forget to add a `f.hidden_field :project_id, value: @project.id` to your form.

Comment: This is great - right along the lines of what I was looking for. If you could elaborate and make your answer more comprehensive, I think it merits an upvote and checkmark. I've figured out that "fields_for" does not need the ID, Rails convention will automatically use the ID of the parent model. The parent model, as you've specified, must have a hidden input with its own parent ID.

Comment: Ultimately, the code required for the view is what I was looking for for when you have nested routes with a has many nested "fields_for".

Comment: A bit unclear if I actually helped you solve your problem, and if so, what needs elaborating? I can point you to a general page I wrote on doing nested forms https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms and elaborate demo-project (for use with cocoon) https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo But bottom line remains your case is special because you have a nested form, on a nested route, in which case you do have to manually add the parent-id (the project-id --your comment above is confusing because you use parent twice but I think I understood it).

Comment: The more general ruby on rails guide is very complete (and probably more appropriate) on [nested forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms)